# jQuery to show hide same class and hide previously open tag

Tags: jquery, toggle

Ive been messing with this for a while.  I have pieced together code that I have found and have not quite found the perfect solution.  It ALMOST works.  I am using php to turn a text string into a faq section by adding `<p>` tags to every line from a text string.  Then I am using jquery to add classes to each `<p>`.  Then I have jQuery hide show toggle so when a question is clicked the answer is displayed.  I have that working.  What I need now is to have jQuery hide the other answers when a different question is clicked.  Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $ ('#faq p:even').addClass('question');
                $ ('#faq p:odd').addClass('answer');

                $('.answer').hide();

                $('.question').click(function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();
                    // hide all span
                    var $this = $(this).parent().find('.answer');
                    $(".answer").not($this).hide();

                    // here is what I want to do
                    $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                    });

                });

            });
        </script>
```

and some sample html

```
<div id="faq">
<p class="question">Question 1</p>
<p class="answer">Answer 1</p>
<p class="question">Question 1</p>
<p class="answer">Answer 1</p>
<p class="question">Question 1</p>
<p class="answer">Answer 1</p>
</div>
```

The whole idea is that I can type content into a wordpress editor and turn it into a faq section without a lot of pre-coding.

Comment: Off topic: No need to `preventDefault()` on a paragraph tag. Anchors, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer selector is flawed. It selects all answers as it is. (If each question/answer pair was wrapped in a container element, it would work.)

Why not just get the element following the clicked question?

```
$('.question').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this).next('.answer');
    $(".answer").not($this).slideUp();

    // here is what I want to do
    $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/uvnqspxf/)